the data added by the procedure is not displayed by the function
Hello stackoverflow! when trying to add data using the addproduct procedure, the data is not displayed in the getallproducts function (the data appeared in the tables)
there is data in the products tablecalling the getallproducts function does not display this data
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetAllProducts()
RETURNS TABLE (
    product_id INT,
    name varchar(255),
    price DECIMAL(10, 2),
    brand_name varchar(255),
    category varchar(255),
    color varchar(255),
    sizes varchar[],
    imageurls varchar[]
)
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.product_id,
        p.name,
        p.price,
        b.name AS brand_name,
        cat.name AS category,
        col.color AS color,
        ARRAY_REMOVE(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT s.size_value), NULL) AS sizes,
        ARRAY_REMOVE(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT i.imageurl), NULL) AS imageurls
    FROM
        Products p
        JOIN Brands b ON p.brand_id = b.brand_id
        JOIN Categories cat ON p.category_id = cat.category_id
        JOIN Colors col ON p.color_id = col.color_id
        JOIN Availability a ON p.product_id = a.product_id
        JOIN Sizes s ON a.size_id = s.size_id
        LEFT JOIN Image i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
    GROUP BY
        p.product_id,
        p.name,
        p.price,
        b.name,
        cat.name,
        col.color;

    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AddProduct(
    IN p_product_id INT,
    IN p_name VARCHAR(255),
    IN p_description TEXT,
    IN p_price DECIMAL(10, 2),
    IN p_category_name VARCHAR(255),
    IN p_brand_name VARCHAR(255),
    IN p_material_name VARCHAR(255),
    IN p_color_name VARCHAR(255),
    IN p_size_ids INT[],
    IN p_image_urls TEXT[]
)
AS
$$
DECLARE
    v_image_id INT;
    v_arrival_date DATE := CURRENT_DATE;
    v_category_id INT;
    v_brand_id INT;
    v_material_id INT;
    v_color_id INT;
    v_product_id INT;
BEGIN
    -- Получение идентификатора категории по имени
    SELECT category_id INTO v_category_id FROM Categories WHERE name = p_category_name;

    -- Получение идентификатора бренда по имени
    SELECT brand_id INTO v_brand_id FROM Brands WHERE name = p_brand_name;

    -- Получение идентификатора материала по имени
    SELECT material_id INTO v_material_id FROM Materials WHERE name = p_material_name;

    -- Получение идентификатора цвета по имени
    SELECT color_id INTO v_color_id FROM Colors WHERE color = p_color_name;

    -- Получение следующего доступного image_id
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(image_id), 0) + 1 INTO v_image_id FROM Image;

    -- Вставка записи в таблицу Products
    INSERT INTO Products (product_id, name, description, price, category_id, brand_id, arrival_date, color_id, sold_count)
    VALUES (p_product_id, p_name, p_description, p_price, v_category_id, v_brand_id, v_arrival_date, v_color_id, 0)
    RETURNING product_id INTO v_product_id;

    -- Вставка записей в таблицу Image с выбранными image_id и image_url
    FOR i IN 1..array_length(p_image_urls, 1) LOOP
        INSERT INTO Image (image_id, product_id, imageurl)
        VALUES (v_image_id, v_product_id, p_image_urls[i]);
        v_image_id := v_image_id + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


how can this problem be solved? I don't see any mistake.


We don't have your data. Extract the query from the function and remove the joins one at a time until you find your mistake.

Also, check your transaction management.
